# Как из приложения запустить поиск слова в Гугле?

Tags: java

Хочу из контекстного меню осуществить возможность поиска нужного слова в поисковике браузера. Что-бы нажать кнопку, и открылся браузер с результатами поиска. Предполагаю, что должна же быть какая-то команда в джаве, которая это осуществляет. Помогите, пожалуйста, кто знает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант такой:

```
   if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
         Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.google.com/search?q=запрос"));
   }
```

Гуглится запросом, "открыть ссылку в браузере"
Дополнительно, можно почитать тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226212/how-to-open-the-default-webbrowser-using-java